Как сделать ожидание в AppScript если в одной из колонок есть формула
Есть скрипт который запускается в гугл таблицах. Как работает: на лист в одну строку поступают значения, скрипт копирует их и переносить на другой лист, после переноса стирает все значения в строке на первом листе. В чем возникла проблема в колонке "С" после поступления значений в строку на первый лист отрабатывает формула гугл которая проверяет, что написано в колонке "B" и прописывает в колонку "С" значение найденное, которое соответствует введенной в колонку "В" информации.Формула не всегда успевает отработать и информация на другой лист переносится с пустым значением в колонке "С".
Что нужно: после поступления значений в строку скрипт дождался пока отработает формула, и только после этого переносил записи на другой лист и стирал значения. пример скрипта ниже.
Понимаю ,что нужно сделать паузу не не соображу как записать (((
function addToDatabase() {
          var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("все веденные коды");
          var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("результат");
          var values = ss1.getRange(2, 1, 1, 4).getValues();
          Logger.log(values);
          var lr = ss2.getLastRow();
          var lc = ss2.getLastColumn();
          var values = ss2.getRange(lr+1, 1, 1, lc).setValues(values);
          var clear = ss1.getRange(2, 1, 1, 4).clear({fomatOnly: true, contentsOnly: true});
  
         }


Возможно есть вариант когда через скрипт с начало запускается работа формулы а потом работа скрипта который переносит значения на другой лист а затем стирает значения в строке родительской таблицы. просьба помочь найти решения задачи. Логику понимаю как записать нет(((

и третий вариант который пришел на ум сделать проверку ячейки "С" на наличие в ней данных  и после этого запускать работу скрипта.

Не знаю зачем вы удаляете данные, но догадываюсь.
Могу предложить такие варианты.

Сделать систему флагов - строки которые уже обработаны, и строки которые ещё не обработаны и через скрипт их смотреть.
Переносить данные, когда они не приходят. К примеру, в 01:00
Перенести саму формулу на другой лист и работать с уже перенесёнными данными.


усложнит саму систему и увеличит время проъождения всего сценария данных через таблицу(( но спасибо за идею

не сильно увеличит время обработки данных, но право ваше)

перед getValues() --- Utilities.sleep(10000). В скобках значение в ms. выбирайте тот интервал, который подходит под Вашу задачу.

Utilities.sleep этот вариант не подходит так как у формул нет тайминга и ограничений на количества срабатываний(((

Ну я ответил, исходя из вопроса, "как сделать паузу".  Так понимаю, что Вам надо что-то более оптимальное. Попробуйте заменить формулы тоже скриптом, чтоб не смешивать эти темы.

спасибо за совет. Вы правы скрипты и формулы одновременно очень сложно поймать тайминг. Пошел по пути вашего предложения .

Решение заключалось в отказе от формулы в колонке. Формулу заменили отдельным js, расставив логику и тайминги внутри js. Всем спасибо.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Мы заметили, что ваш ответ требует некоторых уточнений. Прежде чем его опубликовать, рекомендуем ознакомиться с справкой о том, как написать хороший ответ => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
